# Camel split CSV file on regex

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am working on one case where I have csv file with below data

```
100| Some Delimited Data
200| Some Delimited Data
100| Some Delimited Data
400| Some Delimited Data
400| Some Delimited Data
200| Some Delimited Data
```

I am trying to make camel route where

```
when 100
  marshal csv & send to Bean
when 200
  marshal csv & send to bean
```

I am trying to route it with camel.
Example when I do in XML I can parse XML in route

I cannot use Camel-Bindy as I don't have fixed delimiters in row

example

```
Row 1 can have 10 '|' (pipes / delimiter)
Row 2 can have 20 '|' (pipes / delimiter)
Row 3 can have 16 '|' (pipes / delimiter)
```

They are variable in length which I have handled in bean. Is there any way where I can parse or use any regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have fixed delimiters in row"? Could you please provide a more concrete example of your CSV file?

Comment: Your example doesn't really help :) Do you mean to say that row 1 can have 10 columns separated with `|` and row 2 20 columns separated by `|`? Are you always using the pipe character as a delimiter?

Comment: I am using `|` (pipe) as delimiter, currently what I am doing is marshelling into xml & then doing xparse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are always using `|` as a delimiter, you can use the [default CSV support](https://camel.apache.org/csv.html) to load the content as a list of lists, then split the body to get each row as a list and then process that list (row) in your bean:

```
<unmarshal>
    <csv delimiter="|"/>
</unmarshal>
<split>
    <simple>${body}</simple> <!-- Body will be a list of lists -->
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body[0]} == '100'</simple>
            <to uri="bean:processor100"/>
        </when>         
        <when>
            <simple>${body[0]} == '200'</simple>
            <to uri="bean:processor200"/>
        </when>
    </choice>
</split>
```